Macro works with direct argument, but not when argument is set using "let"
Take this macro definition:
(defmacro useless (digit)
  (let ((str-digit (number-to-string digit)))
    `(message ,str-digit)))

It works when I call it directly, with a number as argument:
(useless 2)
=> "2"

But when I wrap it in a let form, it fails:
(let ((n 2))
  (useless n))

with the error:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument numberp n)
  number-to-string(n)
  (let ((str-digit (number-to-string digit))) (list 'message str-digit))

It seems the macro sees n as a symbol, not as the integer defined using the let. I'm sure I'm missing some nuance regarding macros, but I can't figure it out! Can anyone tell me what's going on?

This is definitely a duplicate, but I don't have time to search right now.  What you're missing is that macros do not evaluate their arguments when called.  This is absolutely critical for macros to be able to do what they do.  So 2 gets passed as 2 and n gets passed as n.  (Unlike calls to functions where all arguments are evaluated first.)

What @phils said.

Ah. Ok. I knew that macros didn't evaluate their arguments, but I thought that let would that care of that. But now that I think of it, of course it doesn't; let simply binds the variable to the value, and the body still refers to the variable name. Thanks for taking the time to respond! (And I swear I searched for duplicates, but couldn't find a relevant question...)

if you want to be able to call useless with an argument that isn't a number literal, then you'll need to make sure the argument is only parsed as a number as part of the macro's output (its expansion), not as part of the macro's body itself.
(defmacro useless (digit)
  `(let ((str-digit (number-to-string ,digit)))
    (message str-digit)))

but, if you need the macro's expansion to be different depending on the value of digit, then you'll need to do what you're doing now, using digit in the macro body, which will prevent passing a variable in its place. (unfortunately I can't think of a good example demonstrating when you'd want to do this)

I'll mark this as the answer, but I actually finally found another question that solves my problem here. The trick is to wrap the macro call in an eval to get the value of the argument: (let ((n 2)) (eval \(useless ,n))`

Or your macro could (number-to-string (if (symbolp digit) (eval digit) digit)) to be agnostic to which of the two types was used.
